# Perform a FIND in DOS FOR loop

Tags: loops, cmd, dos

I want to perform a FIND command for all the file extension *.LOG in a directory. How can I achieve it? The below is what I have so far, but it is not working and I do not know where's the problem.

```
for /R C:\folder\log %%i IN (*.LOG) DO (
TYPE %%i | find /I /N "ORA-" >> C:\folder\log\Errorfound.log
ECHO %%i
exit
)
```

Comment: How on earth you were able to create a file named longer than 8+3 characters in dos?!

Comment: find accepts wildcards;' `find /I /N "ORA-" *.log >> C:\folder\log\Errorfound.log`

Comment: Hi Alex. That doesn't work as well. If you had noticed, I already have a %%i in which it parses the filename into it.

Comment: What you have works ok for me .. except you may also end up searching Errorfound.log in the loop, what's wrong with it?

Comment: `…but it is not working and I do not know where's the problem.` - You do not know where the problem is but you somehow know that it is not working. Maybe you could tell us more about it. What exactly is not working? Are there any errors? Knowing that might help us in determining what kind of problem you are having, even if it didn't help *you*.

Comment: Hi Andriy. When I tried without the FOR loop, e.g. TYPE file1.log | find /I /N "ORA-" >> C:\folder\log\Errorfound.log, it works and generated the Errorfound.log with the content that I am looking for. When I changed it to the FOR loop above, the errorfound.log was not generated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use

```
findstr /R /I /N "ORA-" *.log
```

You could also use

```
dir /s /b *.log > input.txt
```

And then use that file as input for your loop

```
for /f "eol=; tokens=1 delims=|" %%i in (input.txt) do ( ... )
```

Some remarks

- your output file is also a .log in the same folder that you're searching in. If you run the program multiple times, the output file will show up in your results and double your # of output lines
- don't use "type [file] | do_it" if you can just use stdin: "< [file] do_it"

Comment: hi pforret, I wish to print the filename that matches the searching string too. I had tried to use /M but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Several people have already given you the answer. To find and filter all Oracle errors into one log, run this command:

```
C:\> findstr /ir ora- C:\folder\log\*.log >> C:\folder\log\OracleErrors.txt
```

which also includes the filenames in every line as you asked.
If you only want to echo the filenames, run this second command separately:

```
C:\> findstr /irm ora- C:\folder\log\*.log
```

So which part of these is "not working" as you so eloquently put it?